# android: git commands don't work in gradle after 2FA set on my git account (BitBucket)

Tags: android, git, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, bitbucket

I usually set versionCode & version Name of the project by git info.
i.e. versionCode describes the latest tag in git repository while versionName stands for the total number of commits from the beginning.

/app/build.gradle would look like following.

```
// ...
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    versionCode evalVersionCode()
    versionName evalVersionName()
    // ...
}
```

And the 2 functions are defined as following.

```
/**
  * Generates versionName by latest tag in GIT
  */
 project.ext.evalVersionName = {
     // git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
     def p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git describe --abbrev=0 --tags")
     def result = p.waitFor() // returns 1
     def versionName = "undefined"
     if (result == 0) {
         versionName = p.getInputStream().readLines().get(0)
     }
     project.logger.debug("versionName: git describe --abbrev=0 --tags => $versionName")
     return versionName // I expect "v0.8.3" here.
 }


/**
 * Generates versionCode by number of commits in GIT
 */
project.ext.evalVersionCode = {
    def p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git rev-list --all --count")
    def result = p.waitFor() // returns 1
    def versionCode = 0
    if (result == 0) {
        versionCode = p.getInputStream().readLines().get(0).toInteger()
    }
    project.logger.debug("versionCode: git rev-list --all --count => $versionCode")
    return versionCode // I expect 639 here.
}
```

This mechanism worked well until I set 2FA in my BitBucket account which has this project's repository.
After setting, this code doesn't work and the 2 functions return just hard-coded results, i.e. "undefined" & 0.

That's because `git` command can't run properly in build phase, that said, `p.waitFor()` returns non-zero.

P.S. The git commands work well in terminal even after 2FA set.

Comment: What does the outputstream and errorstream show you?  Do you get the error message?

Comment: @tim_yates I can't get outputstream because there's no output and just result=1. No error message.